Finding the Inverse Laplace transform using partial fractions
Problem:
Given:
$$ Y(s) =  \dfrac{3s^2 + 6s+ 84} {( s+1 )(s-2)(s^2+ 2s+10) } $$
Find $y(t)$ by computing the inverse Laplace transform.
Answer:
To do this, we use the technique of partial fractions.
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{3s^2 + 6s+ 84} {( s+1 )(s-2)(s^2+ 2s+10) } &=
\dfrac{ A }{s+1 } \dfrac{ B }{s-2 } + \dfrac{ Cs+D }{s^2+ 2s+10 } \\
3s^2 + 6s+ 84 &= A( s-2 )(s^2+2s+10) \\
    & + B( s+1)(s^2+2s+10) + (Cs+D)( s+1)(s-2)
\end{align*}
For the special case of $s = -1$ we have:
\begin{align*}
3(1) + 6(-1)+ 84 &= A( -1-2 )(1+2(-1)+10) + B( -1+1)(1+2(1)+10) \\
    & + (Cs+D)( -1+1)(-1-2) \\
3 - 6 + 84 &= A( -3 )(1+2(-1)+10) + B( 0)(1+2(1)+10) \\
      & + (Cs+D)( 0)(-1-2) \\
81 &= A( -3 )(1-2+10) = -27A  \\
A &= -3
\end{align*}
For the special case of $s = 2$ we have:
\begin{align*}
3(4) + 6(2)+ 84 &= A( 2-2 )(4+2(2)+10) + B( 2+1)(4+2(2)+10) \\
       & + (C(2)+D)( 2+1)(2-2) \\
12 + 12+ 84 &= A( 0 )(4+2(2)+10) + B( 2+1)(4+2(2)+10) + (C(2)+D)( 3)(0) \\
24 + 84 &=  B( 3)(4+2(2)+10) = 3(18)B \\
54B &= 108 \\
B &= 2 \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
3s^2 + 6s+ 84 &= (-3)( s-2 )(s^2+2s+10) \\
    & + 2( s+1)(s^2+2s+10) + (Cs+D)( s+1)(s-2) \\
3s^2 + 6s+ 84 &= ( -3s + 6 )(s^2+2s+10) \\
   & + ( 2s+2)(s^2+2s+10) + (Cs+D)( s+1)(s-2) \\
3s^2 + 6s+ 84 &=
-3s^3 - 6s^2 - 30s \\
    & + 6s^2+12s+60 + ( 2s+2)(s^2+2s+10) + (Cs+D)( s+1)(s-2) \\
%
3s^2 + 6s+ 24 &=
-3s^3 - 6s^2 \\
 &- 30s + 6s^2+12s + ( 2s+2)(s^2+2s+10) + (Cs+D)( s+1)(s-2) \\
%
6s+ 24 &= -3s^3 - 3s^2 \\
  &- 30s + 6s^2+12s + ( 2s+2)(s^2+2s+10) + (Cs+D)( s+1)(s-2) \\
24 &= -3s^3 - 3s^2 \\
   & - 24s + 6s^2+12s + ( 2s+2)(s^2+2s+10) + (Cs+D)( s^2 -s -2) \\
\end{align*}
Now we can solve for $D$ by looking at the constant terms.
\begin{align*}
24 &= 20 - 2D \\
D &= 2 \\
\end{align*}
Now we can solve for $C$ by looking at the terms with $s^3$ in them.
\begin{align*}
0 &= -3 + 2 + C \\
C &= 1 \\
\end{align*}
Hence, we have:
\begin{align*}
Y(s) &= \dfrac{ -3 }{s+1 } + \dfrac{ 2 }{s-2 } + \dfrac{ s+2 }{s^2+ 2s+10 } \\
Y(s) &=
\dfrac{ -3 }{s+1 } + \dfrac{ 2 }{s-2 } + \dfrac{ s }{(s+1)^2 + 9 }
+ \dfrac{ 2 }{(s+1)^2 + 9 } \\
\end{align*}
Using an online integral calculator, I find the answer is:
$$ y = e^{-t} ( 2e^{3t}  - \sin(3t) + \cos(3t) - 3)$$
Hence, I believe the value I found for $D$ to be wrong. I just do not know where I made the mistake.

If $24 = 20 - 2D$ then $D = {\color{red}-}2.$ Then, when splitting the
$$
\frac{s-2}{s^2 + 2\,s+10}
$$
term you need to write it so that you can use the exponential shift theorem correctly. I.e.,
$$
\frac{s-2}{s^2 + 2\,s+10}
=
\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2 + 9} + \frac{-3}{(s+1)^2 + 9}
$$
Verify that the transform would now agree.
